# Raw H265: How to tell which bytes are equal to a whole video frame?

Tags: hevc, h.265

I have a raw `H265` video file. I want to understand the exact mechanism to tell which bytes are separating every frame and another, in order to send it over the network to be decoded by a remote app.

I have a faint understanding about `NAL units`, and I tried to grasp what `CSD-0`, `CSD-1`, `SPS`, `VPS`, `PPS` are, but I couldn't put two and two together. I tried dividing the entire byte sequence of the file (they call it a bitstream I think) to chunks, on every incidence of a NAL header (00 00 00 01) but the result are just undecodable bytearrays, none of them corresponds to an actual frame.

So, what am I missing ? I welcome any code in any programming language as I have a broad understanding of a variety of languages, what matters here is the algorithm that is used to detect frames in a byte sequence of a raw H265 video file.

This is a small snippet of the bytearrays I obtain if I divide the entire file using only NAL headers. I noticed some patterns but I can never guess which sequence is actually starting a full frame.

```
00 00 00 01 44 00 E0 7E B0 26 40 
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
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 3E 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 01 02 00 D0 0D C4 1F 80 43 68 04 81 7F 49 2C 0A 52 22 CE 00 8C 00 6E 7A 6F A4 00 3F E5 A5 F0 A7 79 4B 08 67 2E 90 00 F6 72 1A 6D 14 16 53 32 24 EC A6 D6 00 87 33 55 65 27 C7 00 A0 91 ED 3C 13 00 00 60 00 11 8D CB 8A 00 CD 00 EA BA BE 00 E8 82 FC CF 23 61 D5 00 D4 B3 96 C1 00 FA 00 EB 00
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 B8 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 
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
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 28 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 
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
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 33 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 
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
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 51 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 
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
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 53 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 
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
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 0B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 01 02 00 D0 3D C4 08 E0 FC 99 48 A5 72 18 EF E8 97 FF 87 68 7E 9C A4 52 00 1B 58 E9 4A B1 1D 15 F8 00 00 23 00 D2 54 3A E3 64 04 00 BF DB C9 C6 8B 55 5B CF BB 0F D9 73 33 80 9A 00 ED 4C 00 60 00 00 00 00 2D A0 53 00 25 2C 00 00 7B 92 69 00 59 B5 00 0B 5A 42 62 28 75 F5 81 00 00 A3 79 94 F0 50 9F 9D 14 A1 D1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B7 00 00 00 F6 CC 1C D7 00 00 19 00 8A 3F 00 41 00 35 8E 00 B9 9E E6 00 7A CE A7 13 43 00 00 B0 00 6F 00 D4 BA 5F 65 AA 00 00 00 00 DF 00 00 06 00
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 8C 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 
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
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 43 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 
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
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 AA 37 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 01 40 00 0C 00 FF 00 00 60 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 96 AC 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 29 A0 
00 00 00 01 42 00 00 00 60 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 96 A0 0B 08 04 85 00 B9 24 C9 AE 59 CD C1 81 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 64 00 
00 00 00 01 44 00 E0 7E B0 26 40 
00 00 00 01 26 00 AF 1F 80 05 67 5C CE 4A 0C 42 B8 29 A0 3F DE 25 7B 72 57 BB BE 9D 5A F6 CD E6 D9 35 54 B3 8F FB BD 23 1B 00 2E AC AA 03 00 6F A4 CC 8C 8E 00 65 22 8B 7F F0 1E 6C 91 00 1A 00 00 FF F1 C9 98 00 00 2B 00 E8 81 A9 3E 4D 96 99 5D 00 2A 00 00 C3 00 00 A8 00 33 6B 00 32 D5 B2 E9 E2 00 F8 00 02 00 46 EA CF DB 00 F5 7C C0 00 00 B1 00 00 00 00 40 76 1C 3C 62 3D 5B 4B 79 00 00 EF 8D 07 58 11 50 00 00 0E 36 48 20 00 53 00 38 00 82 00 0D FE 00 DF D4 4C 85 34 00 83 F4 00 E3 00 00 D6 F3 00 6D 00 51 9C 14 70 60 00 13 56 00 E5 21 00 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 C7 09 77 4E CB C2 00 00 B5 00 30 D3 66 00 00 00 00 0F D8 D0 00 00 00 24 00 C5 00 00 F7 00 61 9F 00 A7 00 00 00 00 00 00 31 74 00 FC 00 71 E0 00 EE 00 27 00 9B 00 00 E7 00 00 00 BA 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 00 08 00 00 00 00 17 00 0B B4 00 D1 00 00 00 B9 00 00 F9 00 00 00 00 00 9E 00 EB
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 B5 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 
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
00 00 00 01 00 00 00 EC 05 00 00 00 00 00 00
```